# Retrieve data from many-to-many relationship - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have a 'User' class:

```
public class User implements Serializable { 
@Id 
@GeneratedValue
int id;

String nome;

@Column(unique = true)
String email;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable (name = "user_roles", joinColumns=
    { @JoinColumn (name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns=
    { @JoinColumn (name = "role_id")})
private List<Role> roles;
```

I have a 'Role' class:

```
public class Role implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id 
@GeneratedValue
int id;

@Column(unique = true)
String role;
```

**Relationship** :An User has roles, and roles has users. I have a many-to-many relationship here. The relation is unidirectional, and my dominant entity is User.

In my database has a table named "user_roles", created automatically. I have a User registered with two roles.

When I retrieve the User from my database using a "UserDao" class, and I try to access the roles of the user, I get NullPointerException. I got all others informations (name, email, etc), but the roles I can not access.

My 'UserDao' class:

```
public class UserDaoImpl implements UserDao{

private static final transient Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserDaoImpl.class);
private final String HIBERNATE_CFG = "data.cfg.xml";
    @Override
    public int insertUser (User user){
    int code = 0;

    Session session = new HibernateUtil(HIBERNATE_CFG).getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        code = 1;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        code = 0;
    }

    return code;
} 

@Override
public List<User> getAll() {
    Session session = new HibernateUtil(HIBERNATE_CFG).getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    List<User> users = null;

    try
    {
        session.beginTransaction();
        String queryString = "SELECT * FROM USER;";
        SQLQuery consulta = session.createSQLQuery(queryString);
        consulta.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));
        users = (List<User>) consulta.list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }
    catch(ConstraintViolationException e)
    {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    return users;
}
```

I tried using iterator:

```
List roles = user.getRegras();
    for (Iterator it = roles.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
        Role r = (Role) it.next();
        out.println("Role:" + r.getRole());
    }
```

I tried to instantiate the variable "roles" in the 'User' class like below. But every time the variable returns size 0:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable (name = "user_roles", joinColumns=
{ @JoinColumn (name = "user_id")}, inverseJoinColumns=
{ @JoinColumn (name = "role_id")})
private List<Role> regras = new ArrayList<Role>();
```

I tried getting the roles from Object User, but I receive a NullPointerException when the method size() is called.

```
List<Role> roles = (List<Role>)user.getRoles();
out.println("size roles: "  + roles.size());
```

I'm trying to acess my table 'user_roles' to retrieve the data from database, but I can't dothis. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your mapping looks OK. Turn on SQL logging to see the generated queries. Then, run the queries directly on DB to check if it returns any results.

Comment: Could you post code for UserDAO class?

Comment: @PredragMaric His Hibernate code is riddled with problems.  Please do not post that everything is OK unless you are quite certain that there are really no problems.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was referring to the `@ManyToMany` mapping, which is OK.

Comment: He was missing the `mappedBy` annotation, which I believe will cause problems.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen He said that relation is unidirectional, no need for `mappedBy`.

Comment: @LalitRao I inserted the UserDAO in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a SQL query to load the users, and mapping the result to the entity. So what you get is detached entities, containing only what the SQL query returned.

Learn to use JPQL/HQL, and to load entities, which will then be managed:

```
    String queryString = "SELECT u FROM User u";
    Query consulta = session.createQuery(queryString);
    users = (List<User>) consulta.list();
```

Comment: When I get the list using the HQL, I got this exception: 

failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Comment: Google the exception, and understand what it means and how to avoid it. There are dozens of questions regarding this exception already.